# How to Read and Write to RFID as Human Interface Device C#

Tags: c#, hid

Am trying to read/write to card using RFID reader, but the RFID reader is appearing under Human Interface Device, so far I have been able to get all Human Interface Devices into a DropDownlist using
**HidLibrary** here is my code:

```
  HidDevice[] mahdDevices;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mahdDevices = HidDevices.Enumerate().ToArray();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < mahdDevices.Length; i++)
        {
            cmbDevices.Items.Add(mahdDevices[i].Description);
        }
    }
```

But now am not sure of how to send and receive data from the HID selected on the drop downlist, I also checked **Hardware IDs** of RFID device in properties i Found:

> HID\VID_9915&PID_1116&REV_0120,  HID\VID_9915&PID_1116,  HID\VID_9915&UP:85FF_U:0001, HID_DEVICE_UP:85FF_U0001,  HID_DEVICE.

No idea on what to do with the IDs or how to communicate with HID devices, this is how i usually communicate with devices using serial port:

```
  _port = new SerialPort();
        _port.PortName = comboBox2.Text;
        _port.BaudRate = 9600;
        _port.Parity = Parity.None;
        _port.DataBits = 8;
        _port.StopBits = StopBits.One;

        if (_port.IsOpen)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            _port.Close();
        }
        _port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(RFID_DataReceiver);
```

Please I need help communicating with HIDs.

Comment: did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

**The simple way to read:**

If RFID is a HID device, then in most cases it acts as a keyboard. You can read the RFID by reading keyboard input then.

To test if the RFID reader acts as a keyboard then you can test it in a text editor.

**Read/Write using HID protocol**

There is a [project on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1244702/How-to-Communicate-with-its-USB-Devices-using-HID) which explains reading/writing to USB HID device.